# How to display table headers for nested arrays

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table, nested, frontend

I have a nested array in html table. Am able to display the table. However, i have a problem with inserting headers to the nested arrays columns.

Below is the code:
table.js

```
const Table= college?.map((item =>   
      <tr >
       <td> {item.department.map((item,i) => (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{item.studentName}</td>
                    <td>{item.subject}</td>
                    <td>{item.daysClassattended}</td>
                  </tr>                        
             ))} 
       </td>                     
     </tr>
    ));
         return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Student Name </th>
            <th>Subject </th>
            <th>Days Attended Classes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{Table}</tbody>
      </table>;
    </div>
```

What is the best way to insert headers into the nested array table? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your problem to do with using React or how to structure the HTML? (Or both?) What are you trying to achieve in terms of table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert headers to the nested array columns in the HTML table, you can modify the code as follows:

```
const Table = college?.map((item) => {
  return (
    <>
      <tr>
        <th colSpan="3">{item.departmentName}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Days Attended Classes</th>
      </tr>
      {item.department.map((student, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>{student.studentName}</td>
          <td>{student.subject}</td>
          <td>{student.daysClassattended}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
});

return (
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>{Table}</tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to list all the students together without distinguishing their departments, then `flatMap` is an option:

```js
  const Table = college?.flatMap((item =>   
    item.department.map((item,i) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{item.studentName}</td>
        <td>{item.subject}</td>
        <td>{item.daysClassattended}</td>
      </tr>                        
    ))
  ));
```